# redirect the domainname.com website to m.domainname.com in django for mobile devices

Tags: html, django, mobile

I want to redirect the user to m.domainname.com on his mobile browser. I want to use the existing website but redirect to the m.domainname.com. 
For that how can i detect the user is on mobile or desktop.
And how can i redirect the mobile version of same site.

using media screen i can create the seprate displays for mobile divices

using bootstrap i can create the responsive website. but when its on mobile browser i want to redirect the mobile version like m.domainname.com

How can i do this?
And my website is in django.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this: https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile
The idea is to detect mobile device in middleware (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/).

So, if middleware detects that request going from mobile device, and user requested the normal version of the site, you can redirect him to mobile version of the site.